# Concatenate php array elements with url and then pass to ajax API request

Tags: php, json, ajax, api, azure-cognitive-services

I am currently working on a project which get the images(scandir by php) from the server(http://SERVER_IP_ADDRESS/snap/) and then pass it to Microsoft Emotion API for emotion analysis.

However, after I pass the concatenated url to the ajax request, I got below error:

```
Error: {"readyState":4,"responseText":"{\"error\":
{\"code\":\"BadBody\",\"message\":\"JSON parsing error.\"}}","status":400,"statusText":"Bad Request"}
```

My code is like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>JSSample</title>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<h2>Face Rectangle</h2>
<ul id="faceRectangle">
<!-- Will populate list with response content -->
</ul>

<h2>Emotions</h2>
<ul id="scores">
<!-- Will populate list with response content -->
</ul>

<body>

<script type="text/javascript">

<?php
    $dir    = "snap";
    $files2 = scandir($dir, 1); 
?>
    var images = <?php echo json_encode(array_slice($files2, 2), JSON_FORCE_OBJECT); ?>;
//Say I want to get image no.221
    var info = "http://SERVER_IP_ADDRESS/snap/" + images[221]; 

    $(function() {
        // No query string parameters for this API call.
        var params = { };

        $.ajax({
            url: "https://westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/emotion/v1.0/recognize?" + $.param(params),
            beforeSend: function(xhrObj){
                // Request headers, also supports "application/octet-stream"
                xhrObj.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/json");

                // NOTE: Replace the "Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key" value with a valid subscription key.
                xhrObj.setRequestHeader("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key","YOUR_KEY");
            },
            type: "POST",
            // Request body
            data: '{"url": info}',
        }).done(function(data) {
            // Get face rectangle dimensions
            var faceRectangle = data[0].faceRectangle;
            var faceRectangleList = $('#faceRectangle');

            // Append to DOM
            for (var prop in faceRectangle) {
                faceRectangleList.append("<li> " + prop + ": " + faceRectangle[prop] + "</li>");
            }

            // Get emotion confidence scores
            var scores = data[0].scores;
            var scoresList = $('#scores');

            // Append to DOM
            for(var prop in scores) {
                scoresList.append("<li> " + prop + ": " + scores[prop] + "</li>")
            }
        }).fail(function(err) {
            alert("Error: " + JSON.stringify(err));
        });
    });
    //Show the variables
    document.write(images[221]);
    document.write(info);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I tried to remove "JSON_FORCE_OBJECT" in json_encode while the same error shown.

Comment: `{"url": info}` this is not valid json

Comment: @Alexey Sorry I am a newbie on this. But I can't do "info" right? Any ideas on adding the url to `data: '{"url": info}'`? I also failed when I do `data: '{"url":"http://SERVER_IP_ADDRESS/snap/" + images[221];}'`

Comment: Is that even url encoded?

Comment: Remove the single quotes. Right now `'{"url": info}'` is a _string_, not an object. That literal string will be sent to the server, it will not contain the contents of your "info" variable.

Comment: @Progrock Um...The `document.wirte(info);` looks fine. @ADyson Same error occur. I copied the javascript code from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/emotion/quickstarts/javascript

Comment: Based on that, try `data: JSON.stringify({"url": info});` . In other words, you send a string which looks like JSON, but produce that string dynamically from an object which contains your URL, not a static value. Also, we don't know what `images[221]` in your code contains, so we don't know if your final URL value makes sense.

Comment: And, silly question, but can I check that in your real code you replaced "YOUR_KEY" with a valid subscription key?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answered by [ADyson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5947043/adyson): use `data: JSON.stringify({"url": info});`

Original answer:

> Based on that, try data: JSON.stringify({"url": info}); . In other words, you send a string which looks like JSON, but produce that string dynamically from an object which contains your URL, not a static value. Also, we don't know what images[221] in your code contains, so we don't know if your final URL value makes sense. – ADyson

Thank you [ADyson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5947043/adyson) for your help!!!